# Reduce array by counting repeated and remap keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
[{fruit: "Apple", cost: 2},{fruit: "Banana", cost: 3}, {fruit: "Apple", cost: 4}]
```

I just want an array of how many instances of each fruit in this array. So I used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#remove_duplicate_items_in_an_array.
except that it gives me

```
[{"Apple", 2}, {"Banana", 1}]
```

and I'd like it to be

```
[{fruit:"Apple", count:2}, {fruit:"Banana", count:1}]
```

How to remap it to have the desired keys?

```
const reduced = array.reduce((allTypes, item) => {
    if (item in allTypes) {
        allTypes[item] ++;
    }
    else {
    allTypes[item] = 1;
    }

    return allTypes;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

You just need to use reduce(that will give you a single result, array in this case) and `increment` the count if its respective fruit is already present else create a new object with 2 keys `fruit` and `count`. Make new object count to 1 by default.

```js
const arr = [
  { fruit: "Apple", cost: 2 },
  { fruit: "Banana", cost: 3 },
  { fruit: "Apple", cost: 4 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { fruit } = curr;
  const isExist = acc.find((el) => el.fruit === fruit);
  if (isExist) ++isExist.count;
  else acc.push({ fruit, count: 1 });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```js
const data = 
  [ { fruit: 'Apple',  cost: 2 } 
  , { fruit: 'Banana', cost: 3 } 
  , { fruit: 'Apple',  cost: 4 } 
  ] 

const result = data.reduce((acc, {fruit}, i, arr) =>
  {
  if (!acc.some(x=>x.fruit === fruit))
    {
    let count = arr.filter(x=>x.fruit === fruit).length
    acc.push({ fruit, count })
    }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other responses are fine, but I'd like to propose you a one-liner solution, but that returns an `object` instead of an `array of objects`.

```
arr.reduce((acc, { fruit }) => ({ ...acc, [fruit]: (acc[fruit] || 0) + 1 }), {})
// returns {Apple: 2, Banana: 1}
```

I think it servers your use case, as the result you want is the count value mapped by the fruit name as key, anyway.

If you really need an array of objects, you can convert the result of the previous expression `x` by doing this:

```
Object.entries(x).map(([f, c]) => ({ fruit: f, count: c}))
```